# Calculating Turnaround Time in Date Fields

Tags: formula

Does anyone know if there is a formula to calculate the turnaround time between 2 date fields and exclude weekend days?

Ex: Case opened 11/30/12, case closed 12/4/12 - how many days did it take to close the case excluding Sat and Sun.

Comment: I've created a similar question to address the same problem from Apex - [Days between two DateTime values excluding weekends](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/days-between-two-datetime-values-excluding-weekends)

Answer (score 5):

Check this post : http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000KC20EAG (look all way below for the comment posted by NZgon)

I tried the code and works too just in case : 
This gives you the difference between 2 days as number excluding the weekends ( make sure the formula field is a number field)

```
CASE(MOD( StartDate__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 

0 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
1 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
2 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
3 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
4 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
5 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
6 , CASE( MOD( EndDate__c - StartDate__c ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
999) 
+ 
(FLOOR(( EndDate__c - StartDate__c )/7)*5)
```

**EDIT TO ANSWER IF THE FIELDS ARE DATE TIME VALUES:** As per the posting above change all the date values to DateVALUE(Date) in short change all the startDate_*c to DATEVALUE(startdate*_c) and EndDate_*c to DATEVALUE(EndDate*_c), **doing replace all in notepad++ will avoid the hazzle of figuring which bracket you missed**.

```
CASE(MOD( DATEVALUE(startDate__c) - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 

  0 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(EndDate__c) - DATEVALUE(startDate__c) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
  1 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(EndDate__c) - DATEVALUE(startDate__c) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
  2 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(EndDate__c) - DATEVALUE(startDate__c) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  3 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(EndDate__c) - DATEVALUE(startDate__c) ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  4 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(EndDate__c) - DATEVALUE(startDate__c) ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  5 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(EndDate__c) - DATEVALUE(startDate__c) ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
  6 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(EndDate__c) - DATEVALUE(startDate__c) ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
  999) 
  + 
  (FLOOR(( DATEVALUE(EndDate__c) - DATEVALUE(startDate__c) )/7)*5)
```

Comment: Holy cow... I'm too sober to understand the mad genius behind that one, maybe I'll figure it out as a weekend homework :D Amazing. And scary.

Comment: I can't understand it all, but it worked like a charm! Thank you! Now to take it a step further, what if the turnaround time you are trying to capture in business days is off of date/time fields? Not just date fields? Date/Time Opened versus Date/Time closed....

Comment: You are my hero - thank you so much for your help on this!!!

Comment: Most welcome :)!!! Happy I was able to help you out!!

Comment: Hey all! Yep it worked well, I have a problem concerning a half days! I want to count a half days as well! any idea?