# Business days calculation in apex

Tags: apex

How to calculate the business days difference between two dates in APex?
I'm going to pass firstdate and finishdate from batch apex(below class is going to call in batch apex). I need to calculate only business days difference.

```
public with sharing class DaysDifferenceForTimeLog {
    public static integer EndDateStartDateDifferenceForTimeLog(date firstDate, date finishDate) {
        
        integer difference= firstDate.daysBetween(finishDate);
        return difference;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/days-between-two-datetime-values-excluding-weekends?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

try below :-

```
/*
 * Get numbe of business days between two dates
 *
 * */
public Integer getNoOfBusinessDaysBetweenDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate){
    Integer count = 0;
    
    BusinessHours bHours = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true limit 1];
     
    while(startDate <= endDate){
        if(BusinessHours.isWithin(bHours.Id, startDate)){
            count++;
        }
        startDate = startDate.addDays(1);
    }
    return count;
}
```